# AsyncTask call native method

Tags: android, android-asynctask, java-native-interface

I have an AsyncTask and am trying to call a native(jni) method from it.  Is it possible? I am getting a runtime exception saying unsatisfied link error.

Comment: yes, it is possible. the issue is most likely in the way you include the jni lib

Comment: I am including it in the same way as in an activity, system.loadlibrary("libraryname"), but it is not working.  Can I do something else to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can call JNI methods from any thread, including those used for an AsyncTask.  The problem is likely either:

1. That the native library is not loaded in time. Maybe you have a race condition here now you are using multiple threads?  Are you loading the library on the main thread, racing with the JNI call in the background thread?
2. That you have a signature mismatch between your native method stub on the Java side and the method implementation on the native side.

Comment: I am loading the library in the main activity and using it in an asynctask in the onResume method.  If i call the native library from the onResume method, commenting asynctask it works fine.  The same thing when called from asynctask does not work giving me unsatisfied link error with the library.

Comment: Are you moving the native method stub itself into the AsyncTask?  That would change its signature.  To be honest it's difficult to guess what's going on without the code.

Comment: Figured it out, I was not changing the name of the class in the signature of the native library.

Comment: Java_packageName_ClassName_MethodName(JNIEnv *env).  The AsyncTask thread was a different class altogether.  Hence by changing it to Java_packageName_AsyncTask_MethodName(JNIEnv *env), it worked.  Thanks.

Comment: @whiteShadow Also make sure in your native library that you are always using the `env` parameter passed with the call from Java not a cached version of it. I saw this a several times in "wildlife" and this can cause you troubles sometimes when using the library with different threads simultanuosly.