# Using JNI in an async task. Having a runtime error: JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION : use of invalid jobject

Tags: java, android, c++, android-asynctask, java-native-interface

I am working on a server/client app. The client side is on an Android device. An async task is used for sending data to a server. But when I try to use JNI function to process data, I have following errors.

```
 JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of invalid jobject 0xb2f93d20
     from void com.labtest.dbclient.Conversation.send(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
 "AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=17 Runnable
   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12e28550 self=0xa38ae600
   | sysTid=24815 nice=10 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0x9014f920
   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
   | stack=0x9004d000-0x9004f000 stackSize=1038KB
   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
   native: #00 pc 00572f1e  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+238)
   native: #01 pc 0053f30e  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+526)
   native: #02 pc 0053c30b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+75)
   native: #03 pc 00392418  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2_+1560)
   native: #04 pc 00392dcc  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortFEPKcS2_z+124)
   native: #05 pc 00544d53  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread13DecodeJObjectEP8_jobject+451)
   native: #06 pc 0000005d   (???)
   at com.labtest.dbclient.Conversation.send(Native method)
   at com.labtest.dbclient.Conversation.doInBackground(Conversation.java:108)
   at com.labtest.dbclient.Conversation.doInBackground(Conversation.java:21)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

The native c++ code is:

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_labtest_dbclient_Conversation_send(
        JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj, jstring in_info, jstring in_data)
{
    const char *ptr_info = env->GetStringUTFChars(in_info, NULL);
    const char *ptr_data = env->GetStringUTFChars(in_data, NULL);
... 
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(in_info, ptr_info);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(in_data,ptr_data);
}
```

The Java code is:

```
public class EncryptedTcpClient extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    public native void send(String in_info, String in_data);

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... in_params){
    ...
    send(in_params[0], in_params[1]);
    ...
    }
｝
```

Anyone knows what might be the cause of the errors?

Edit 1:
I found that the invalid jobject is the first parameter of the nvative funcion.`jstring in_info`. But I am 100% sure the parameter is initialized with valid value. I also suspected the VM crash might have something to do with using native function in an async task. But based on the the question [AsyncTask call native method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022735/asynctask-call-native-method). 
It is fine to use the native function in an async task.

Edit 2:
I could resolve the errors but I still do not know the cause of the issue. In the gradle, I have following settings

```
ndk{
    // There is a compile error on MIPS architecture
    // so the MIPS is excluded from the project
    abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a'
}
```

And I was using x86 architecture emulator. I removed 'x86' and use the x86_64 architecture emulator, the problem is gone.

```
ndk{
    // There is a compile error on MIPS architecture
    // so the MIPS is excluded from the project
    abiFilters 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a'
}
```

But, so it seems to me that the app is not able to generate correct binary for x86 machine, or maybe I missed some configuration steps to let android studio to deploy proper binary on the device? Or should I just remove the abi filter to generate a fat package?

environement:

android studio 2.3.3
android SDK: 26.0.0
compileSdkVersion: 25
targetSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion 25.0.2
ndk r15b 15.1.4119039
os Ubuntu 16.0.4.2 LTS

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40508242/how-to-debug-jni-detected-error-in-application-use-of-invalid-jobject . My two cents: I would use nio's memory mapped files to provide a safe communication boundary between native and java

Comment: What are the values of the `jstring` and `jobject` variables passed to your native function?  Which one is the bad one?  It could be one of the strings, but I'd output the actual values just to be sure.  You may learn something - or not.

Comment: @ efekctive, thanks for your comments, I believe memory mapped files will fix concurrency problem, if the native code runs different thread I will need that, but I was calling native withing the asynctask. Anyway it was a good suggestion, Thanks.

Comment: @Andrew Henle, based on the way I resolve the issue, I think something weird happened in art, the VM. But I could not figure it out. The address in x86 was 8 bytes and looks valid to me. But not to the VM. The string parameter value was also valid. e.g If I pass "ABC" from java function `async::doInBackground()`(well, I know it is not a valid java code, but I hope you get what I am trying to say) to native code. The value of the string is unchanged in the native code. It just art keep popping up error messages.